# Spring Integration http:inbound-gateway payload type

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have an HTTP inbound gateway

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway name="/purchase"
    supported-methods="GET" request-channel="purchaseRequest"
    reply-channel="purchaseReply"
    request-payload-type="com.myapp.PurchaseRequest" />
```

What is the format that I have to call the URL to populate the PurchaseRequest object rather than submit a `LinkedMultiValueMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
request-payload-type
```

attribute doesn't apply for GET, HEAD and OPTIONS methods.

If you can upgrade to 2.1, and you have an appropriate constructor on your PurchaseRequest object, you could use

```
payload-expression="new com.myapp.PurchaseRequest(#requestParams['param1'], #requestParams['param2'], ...)"
```